# Recursively Traverse a Binary Search Tree And Print Out Data In Columns

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have constructed a binary search tree using a text file that is read in by the main function. The resulting tree contains the words of the text file, with a count so that the same word is not inserted twice. The problem is not with constructing the tree, but getting the information to display properly. The data is required to be printed out in columns of 4, as to keep it readable.

Example:

```
|BTNode1|BTNode2|BTNode3|BTNode4|  
|BTNode5|BTNode6|BTNode7|BTNode8|
```

The `BTNode` class has a `toString()` method that prints out the data of the individual nodes. But, whenever I call this code below with the root node, and a count of 0 I get the node information properly, but in weird numbers of nodes per column. Any ideas how to get this to work? I can post additional code if necessary.

EDIT: Added entire class to reflect changes, and added sample current output. Might be a problem with constructing the tree.

EDIT2: Changed `printcount = 1`, fixes the display problems. Code now works properly.

```
package speech;

public class BSTree {
private BTNode root;
private final String DISPLAY_FORMAT_CAPS =
    "*****************************************************************";
private StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
private int printcount = 1;
public BSTree (){
    root = null;
}

public BTNode insert(String indata, boolean lowercase){
    if(lowercase){
        if(root != null){
            return insertRecursive(root,indata.toLowerCase());
        }
        else{
            root = new BTNode(indata.toLowerCase());
            return root;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(root != null){
            return insertRecursive(root,indata);
        }
        else{
            root = new BTNode(indata);
            return root;
        }

    }

}

private BTNode insertRecursive(BTNode node, String value) {
    if (value.compareTo(node.data) < 0){
        if (node.left != null) {
            return insertRecursive(node.left, value);
        } else {
            //System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to left of Node " + node.data);
            node.left = new BTNode(value);
            return node.left;
        }
    } else if (value.compareTo(node.data) > 0) {
        if (node.right != null) {
            return insertRecursive(node.right, value);
        } else {
            //System.out.println("  Inserted " + value + " to right of Node " + node.data);
            node.right = new BTNode(value);
            return node.left;
        }
    } else if (value.compareTo(node.data) == 0){
        node.incrementCount();
        //System.out.println("Incremented count of " + value + " to: " + node.wordcount);
        return node;
    }
    return null;
}

private int wordcountRecursive(BTNode node){
    if(node == null){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return wordcountRecursive(node.left) + node.wordcount + wordcountRecursive(node.right);
    }
}

public int wordcount(){
    return wordcountRecursive(root);
}

public void display(){
    System.out.println(DISPLAY_FORMAT_CAPS);
    displayRecursive(root);
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
    System.out.println(DISPLAY_FORMAT_CAPS);
    System.out.println("Word Count:" + wordcount());

}


private void displayRecursive (BTNode node){
    //System.out.println(count);
    if(node != null){
        displayRecursive(node.left);
        addNodeDisplay(node);       
        displayRecursive(node.right);

    }

}

private void addNodeDisplay(BTNode node){
    if(printcount % 4 != 0){
        buffer.append("|").append(node);
    }
    else{
        buffer.append("|").append(node).append("|\n");
    }
    printcount++;
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you split the traversal and the 4-column consturction into 2 methods?

Comment: @AdamArold Not sure if that is acceptable as part of the assignment, but I could instead traverse it and store it in an arraylist and output the data using a standard loop. He did want it recursive though, atleast the traversal would be.

Comment: Your `count++`'s should each be `count + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some sample data and this looks like it works:

```
private void displayRecursive(Node node) {
  displayRecursive(node, 0);
  System.out.println("");
}

private int displayRecursive(Node node, int count) {

  if (node != null) {
    // Do left first.
    count = displayRecursive(node.getLeft(), count);
    // New line?
    if (count > 0 && count % 4 == 0) {
      // End of line.
      System.out.println("|");
    }
    // Then me.
    System.out.print("|" + node);
    count += 1;
    // Then right.
    count = displayRecursive(node.getRight(), count);
  }
  return count;
}

private void test() {
  Node root = new Node("Root");
  Node left = new Node("Left");
  Node right = new Node("Right");
  root.setLeft(left);
  root.setRight(right);
  Node leftLeft = new Node("Left.Left");
  leftLeft.setLeft(new Node("LeftLeftLeft"));
  leftLeft.setRight(new Node("LeftLeftRight"));
  left.setLeft(leftLeft);
  left.setRight(new Node("Left.Right"));
  right.setLeft(new Node("Right.Left"));
  right.setRight(new Node("Right.Right"));
  displayRecursive(root);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  try {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.test();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

static class Node {
  final String data;
  private Node left = null;
  private Node right = null;

  Node(String data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return data;
  }

  /**
   * @return the left
   */
  public Node getLeft() {
    return left;
  }

  /**
   * @param left the left to set
   */
  public void setLeft(Node left) {
    this.left = left;
  }

  /**
   * @return the right
   */
  public Node getRight() {
    return right;
  }

  /**
   * @param right the right to set
   */
  public void setRight(Node right) {
    this.right = right;
  }
}
```

it prints:

```
|LeftLeftLeft|Left.Left|LeftLeftRight|Left|
|Left.Right|Root|Right.Left|Right|
|Right.Right
```

Comment: Not even close :) I do appreciate the help though, I got the code to work by separating the column construction and traversal methods, makes things much easier.